# Reinstall with existing /home LUKS

Tags: 10.10, encryption, home-directory, luks

My 10.04 machine uses three partitions: 5 GB for `/boot`, 25 GB for `/` and 120 GB for `/home`. `/` and `/home` are encrypted with LUKS passphrase.

I've downloaded the alternate installer in order to reinstall the machine. I want my `/` partition to be rewritten, but to keep my existing `/home`.

Any way to tell the installer my `/home` already exists in a separate LUKS partition?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is to reinstall using `/boot` and `/` and leave the `/home` partition alone during the install. Once you have installed you can install cryptsetup, set up your partition in `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab` and you'll be away. I'll assume you have an encrypted swap For the details, once you have installed and rebooted, open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda6 crypthome
cd /
mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/crypthome /home
```

Edit the partition details and file system type as required. Now you can browse `/home` and ensure it is what you expect. Then you need to put the following in `/etc/crypttab`

```
crypthome /dev/sda6 none         luks
cryptswap /dev/sda7 /dev/urandom swap
```

And in `/etc/fstab` you need to **add** these lines to the end

```
/dev/mapper/crypthome  /home  ext4  defaults  0  2
/dev/mapper/cryptswap  none   swap  sw        0  0
```

Do a reboot to check it all works as expected and you're away :)

Comment: I wanna do pretty much the same but use a partition with custom password. I use pam_mount to automount the partition but it fails on Oneiric. Maybe you can have a look at it http://askubuntu.com/questions/73435/pam-mount-wont-automount-encrypted-partiton