# Drive Encryption - Situation after reinstall/upgrade?

Tags: encryption, home-directory

I am considering encrypting my `/home` directory (I always have it in a separate drive partition) while I do a fresh install of upcoming 12.04 release. I have some concerns in this regard:

1. Now I am running Ubuntu 11.10. Can I encrypt my present `home` while installing Ubuntu 12.04. Will it work fine if I do it while installing beta release?
2. What precautions do I need to take while going for a fresh Ubuntu install later on? Is something like retaining the same password necessary for accessing the directory after the install process (I will be maintaining same `home` directory)?
3. What would be the situation if I forget my password? If I do a password reset at startup will I continue to have access to encrypted directory?

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13211/reinstall-with-existing-home-luks). On your first question, you can't encrypt your existing /home while installing. You choose to either format /home or leave it untouched. On #3, if you forget your password your data is gone, unless you keep a backup somewhere else (which answers part of #2).

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want /home on its own partition formatted and encrypted using dm-crypt, or do you want to use Ubuntu's native Encrypted Home Directory feature?  If the latter, its just a matter of clicking the checkbox in the graphical desktop installer.

Comment: My initial intention was to use Ubuntu's native encryption technology. If `dm-crypt` provides better security I can opt for that..